DLT watermark name 'window' is not defined
I'm reading from a streaming table:
df = spark.readStream.option("ignoreChanges", "true").table(hierarchy)

For simplicity let's just say I need to get records where the column LEVEL is the highest.
Originally I was just going to work out the max LEVEL and apply a filter on the df
max_level = df.agg(max(col("LEVEL"))).collect()[0][0]
df = df.filter(col("LEVEL") == max_level)

But I get this error:
pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()

I then tried a different approach where I would create another dataframe and joining to it instead:
max_level = df.agg(max("LEVEL").alias("LEVEL"))
df = df.join(max_level, "LEVEL").select(df.columns)

But I get this error:
Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;

So I had a go at watermarking:
max_level = df.alias("df").withWatermark("UpdateDate", "10 minutes").groupBy(window(col("df.UpdateDate"), "10 minutes", "5 minutes"),col("df.Database")).agg(max("LEVEL").alias("LEVEL"))
df = df.alias("df").join(max_level.alias("max"), "LEVEL").select(*[col("df." + x) for x in df.columns])

But now I'm getting this error:
NameError: name 'window' is not defined

Feels like I'm close maybe just somewhere has gone wrong with the watermark, can anyone assists please?

Did you try adding this?
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

More info:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Window.html
